# React Native - SectionList scroll to end when list is loaded first time

Tags: react-native

I am working on a chat application.
I am using `SectionList` to render messages. 
I want to scroll to bottom when list loaded. 
All messages are of dynamic size so there is no possibility to use `getItemLayout`. 
If I call `scrollToLocation` immediately, `SectionList` throws error that `scrollToLocation should be used in conjunction with getItemLayout`.

How can I achieve this?

```
loadNextPage() {
    var dataSource = this.message_list.load_next_page()
    this.setState({ data : dataSource, 
                    isLoading:false,
                    isPullToRefreshing:false})    
}

onMessagesReceived() {
    this.loadNextPage()
    this.scrollToEnd()
}

scrollToEnd(animated) {
    var length = this.state.data.length
    if(length > 0) {
    setTimeout(()=> {
        this.refs.chatList.scrollToLocation({animated:animated, 
                                       sectionIndex:length-1,
                                      itemIndex:this.state.
                                      data[length-1].data.length-1,
                                       viewPosition:1})
      }, 10)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Could u share your code and the error thrown..

Comment: updated qustion

Comment: If I add some delay it works fine.. but problem is delay is different for both platforms. 200ms on iOS and about 1s on android. but I don't want to use such hacks

Comment: "Without getItemLayout, your list can’t know how long it will be until you get to the last row....." you cannot do scrollTo until everything rendered. To more details u may read further of this article - https://medium.com/@jsoendermann/sectionlist-and-getitemlayout-2293b0b916fb . Im suggest u, if u want to do for chat application which always refer to newest at the bottom of list, use inverted method. U may try to use other component such as react-native-invertible-scroll-view.

Comment: I tried Invertible scroll view but its not working.. Maybe I am doing something wrong